# Emacs: new line and automatic indentation in Java mode

Tags: emacs

I am new to Emacs. The Emacs that I am using now is not performing automatic indentation in Java mode. My problem can be best exemplified by the example below. Let | represent the cursor.

When I type:

```
public class Testing{
      public static void main(String[] args){|}
}
```

and press ENTER , the code becomes:

```
public class Testing{
      public static void main(String[] args){
|}
}
```

But this is not what I want. What I want is this (new line with auto-indentation):

```
public class Testing{
      public static void main(String[] args){
             |
      }
}
```

Can someone suggest what code I should add to the `init.el` file ?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already try the following to indent upon `ENTER`?

```
(global-set-key (kbd "RET") #'newline-and-indent)
```